# 38 kHz signal arduino demodulation

Tags: arduino, infrared, modulation, keyboard, demodulation

I need to demodulate signal with frequency 38 kHz coming from remote controller without IR receiver. I need to demodulate it and as a result get information from it. Is there any examples of similar task? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: How is the data modulated onto the signal?

Comment: You MUST have some form of "receiver". eg a photodiode or ...? You MUST explain the hardware and why you wish to use no IR receiver. IR signal detection can be much harder that most people realise. Gettin the detectors sensitive enough can be challenging. What range? What environment? What ...?

Comment: Totally agree with Russell - you can buy an IR receiver/decoder ic (simple 3 pin device) that will allow you simple access to the data. Take a look at http://www.fibidi.com/arduino-ir-receiver-module/

Answer (score 1):

Those [3-pin decoders](http://www.fibidi.com/arduino-ir-receiver-module/) Jim mentioned are cheap and very easy to hook up.  I pulled one off of a destroyed toy helicopter so I could use its remote to control a robot.  Unfortunately, I've lost the code I used.

This outputs a series of pulses, which you will need to time. This is easiest with a logic analyzer, a little harder with an oscilloscope, but doable with just an arduino.  Once you have a stream of pulse lengths, you can find patterns in pairs of short and long pulses and assign those to ones and zeros, then decode the individual fields.  [Here's](http://www.instructables.com/id/Puzzlebox-Orbit-Using-an-Arduino-to-Control-an-In/?ALLSTEPS) an instructable with some more details.